# Validate a single variable or an array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to validate a single variable like this `$name = "example name"` but I didn't a way to handle it then I decided to convert it to an array like this `$nameArr = ['name' => 'example name'];`, the validator is

```
$rules =
   $this->validate($nameArr, [
     'name' => 'required|max:10|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/u',
   ], [
      'name.required' => 'name is empty',
      'name.max' => 'name must be more less than 10 letters',
      'name.regex' => 'invalid name'
   ]
 );
```

but the Laravel gives this error

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given

Comment: I am just curious to know is it a post request ? and whats the single variable? Is it a value you are getting in route parameter from url?

Comment: @Mihir Bhende It's not post request, the controller gets a data by get url and validate the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, the [`validate`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html#method_validate) function on [`Controller`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php) comes from [`Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html) and requires the first paramter to be a request object.

If you want to validate an array, you will have to [create the validator manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators).

```
$validator = Validator::make($nameArr, 
    [
        'name' => 'required|max:10|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/u',
    ], 
    [
        'name.required' => 'name is empty',
        'name.max' => 'name must be more less than 10 letters',
        'name.regex' => 'invalid name'
    ]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd($validator->errors());
}
```

Comment: You can get a MessageBag using `$validator->errors()` and [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages) shows how to use this errorbag.

Answer (score 0):

After knowing that the parameter is passed as route url param, I would like to add another option which Laravel provides to validate :

```
Route::get('user/{name}', 'UserProfileController@getByName')
->where([ 'name' => '[a-z]{10,}' ]);
```

The `where` method validates the route param based on provided regular expressions. So `[a-z]{10,}` will make sure the name is present with 10 or more characters.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing) for more